# What are dictionary based features in Chinese Word Segmentation in core NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I see dictionary based features in Chinese Word Segmentation in Core NLP but there is no explanation on what they are or what they signify. 
I traced the code to see where it is calculated and I see it is in "Sighan2005DocumentReaderAndWriter.java" file in function "addDictionaryFeatures". I still don't understand the details of it. There are no comments in the code or in the file.
It would be great help if someone could explain what is going on in this function or point me to some place which does.